# Now that I have successfully set-up a users-role_user-roles tables and connection between them, how do I use the roles in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I have seeded 1 user with the role of admin, and every new user who registers will be assigned a role of user. The roles are in a table called roles, the users are in a table called users and the connection between these 2 is in a table called role_user. Now I can't exactly figure out how to, for example, change my header to include admin menu if the logged user is an admin.

Header.blade.php

```
<section class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Images</a></li>
                @auth
                <li><a href="{{ route('upload') }}">Upload</a></li>
                <li class='logOut'><a href="{{ route('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                @endauth
                @guest
                <li class="signUp">Sign Up</li>
                <li class="logIn">Log In</li>
                @endguest
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    public function images(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }

    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Database tables

```
Table - users
Columns - id, username, password

Table - roles
Columns - id, name, description

Table - role_user
Columns - id, user_id, role_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your model for checking role

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;


       public function roles(){
             return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
       }

       public function hasRole($roleName){
          $result = false;
          foreach($this->roles as $role){
              if($role->name == $roleName)
              $result = true ;
          }

         return $result;
      }
}
```

And in your views

```
@if((\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')
    @include('admin.nav')
@endif
```

Comment: How do I pass the $user variable to my view?

Comment: @Bobimaru don't pass if you don't have, I will update the answer

Comment: Hmmm, I get "Call to a member function hasRole() on null"

Comment: @Bobimaru Because user is not logged in

Comment: Oh right, I included auth and endauth before what you said for me to write in the view and I don't get the error anymore. Unfortunately, I don't see the <li>Admin</li> that was supposed to be shown to admin users for some reason.